# Removing 64-bit support for a separate file (compile flag?) xcode

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, compiler-flags, arm64

I am using some c files in my objective-c project that stopped working. I figured out that the problem disappears when I remove arm64 from the Valid Architectures option in Build Settings. I have very limited experience in c and would rather not rewrite all of the c files.

My question is if there is a way for me to remove arm64 support for only a few of my files instead of turning it off for the whole project.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like you need to either settle for 32 bits or dig into the code and figure out why it doesn't like running in 64 bits.

Comment: It is not possible to mix 32bit and 64bit that way. To build 64bit application, all files must be compiled as 64bit.